# Orienational order parameter in isotropic systems

Tags: phase-transition, disorder

I have what may be a dummy question. In NMR or in the study of liquid crystals for example, an order parameter $S$ is often used:
$$
S=\left\langle\frac{1}{2}\left(3\cos^2\theta−1\right)\right\rangle
$$
with $\theta$ the angle of the molecule with a "director" (the magnetic field in NMR, the normal to a membrane for lipids, the global direction in a nematic phase etc). $S$ corresponds to a second-order Legendre polynomial.
I have often read that in an isotropic environment, $S=0$ whereas when all the molecules are well aligned with the reference vector (director), $S=1$. I understand why $S=1$ as $\theta=0$° but I can't find why $S=0$ when all the orientations are random.
Can anyone help me?

Liam

Answer (score 0):

For an isotropic substance,
$$S=\left\langle\frac{1}{2}\left(3\cos^2\theta−1\right)\right\rangle=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi}\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{2\pi}d\chi\,\frac{1}{2}\left(3\cos^2\theta−1\right)=0.$$

Comment: Could you perhaps define all the quantities involved and provide a bit more context?